# Rack + Thin, unlimited connections?

Tags: rack, thin, connection

I have my own MVC environment running with Rack and Thin.

By default, thin's connections are restricted to 1024. How to change the maximum amount of available connections? In best case, to unlimited available connections.

Joern

Comment: I would also like to know how the answer to this, for the opposite reason of limiting number of possible connections for testing.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, this is not possible via any route from `rackup -s thin`, as Thin's config options are not exposed via `rackup -O`, just via parsing ARGV.

However, the following should work:

```
thin -R config.ru --max-conns 2000 --max-persistent-conns 1000 start
```

On my machine Thin refuses to support more than around 10000 connections this way (instead declring it is using the value 2560). Not a problem for me, I'm setting values of 30 and 1 respectively, for testing.

In any case, setting a truly huge number is not advisable, as the service will fail due to resource problems well before it runs out of the connections you have allowed. In fact you can in a small way hasten that process by reserving memory on the server to handle connections that it will never use.